Android Studio take picture to get image
btnCamera.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            val tmpFile = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpg")
            val outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(tmpFile)
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri)
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
        }

when I click the btnCamera button,it trigger btnCamera.setOnClickListener'.
But it execute to
startActivityForResult(intent, 0)' , it execute 'if (logSlowDispatch) {
            showSlowLog(slowDispatchThresholdMs, dispatchStart, dispatchEnd, "dispatch", msg);
        }

, and none of the subsequent code is executed.
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        var picture: Bitmap? = null
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REAUEST_TAKE_PICTURE) {
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/image.jpg"
            )
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }

Do anyone know how to fix , I tried many method , but it all go to the same result, it executes if (logSlowDispatch) { showSlowLog(slowDispatchThresholdMs, dispatchStart, dispatchEnd, "dispatch", msg); }, and it can't execute onActivityResult's method
